(Non)-trivial principal $S^3$-bundles over $d$-dimensional CW-complexes
The question I'm faced with is the following:
For which $d \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 1}$ is any principal $S^3$-bundle over any $d$-dimensional CW-complex $X$ trivial, where we view $S^3 \subseteq \mathbb{H}$, which thus becomes a topological group via the multiplication coming from $\mathbb{H}$.
I've tried using the correspondence that such bundles over $X$ up to isomorphism correspond to homotopy classes $[X,BS^3]$, where $BS^3$ denotes the classifying space of $S^3$, but I wasn't able to conclude anything. Please do note that I have no knowledge in any further obstruction theory, Eilenberg-Maclane spaces whatsoever, so I'm trying to solve this with very basic homotopy and bundle theory. I'm not quite familiar with bundles either.

I take it, then, that you've not seen any other simpler problems, such as the classification of homotopy classes $[X,S^1]$?

@LeeMosher If you're talking about the fact that $S^1$ is $K(\mathbb{Z},1)$ and thus computing homotopy classes $[X,S^1]$ is the same as computing $H^1(X)$ by Brown's representability theorem, then practically, I have not seen it, I'm trying to look for another answer here.

Well, that's one way to do it, hit it with a sledgehammer. But one can figure out $[X,S^1]$ by tapping it with a jeweler's hammer, i.e. by using the simplest obstruction theory. But if you are ruling that out also, then our hands are really tied. Perhaps wait a bit a learn a bit more?

Claim: $[X, BS^3] = *$ for all CW-complexes $X$ of dimension $d$ iff $d < 4$.
We will show this using only the fact that $\pi_k S^3 \cong \pi_{k + 1} B S^3$ and the following rather elementary result:

Lemma: (Compression Lemma) Let $(X, A)$ be a CW-pair and $(Y, B)$ any pair of spaces with $B \neq \emptyset$. If $\pi_n(Y, B, y_0) = 0$ for all $y_0 \in B$ and all $n$ such that $X \setminus A$ has cells in dimension $n$, then every map $f\colon (X, A) \to (Y, B)$ is homotopic rel $A$ to a map $X \to B$.

You can find this lemma together with a proof in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" as Lemma 4.6.
Proof of claim: Note that $[S^4, BS^3] \cong \pi_4 BS^3 \cong \pi_3 S^3 \cong \mathbb{Z} \neq 0$, so there are CW-complexes $X$ of every dimension $\geq 4$ for which $[X, BS^3] \neq *$ (just take a wedge sum of $S^4$ with a disk of the appropriate dimension, say). Conversely, if $\dim X \leq 3$, then since $\pi_k BS^3 = 0$ for $k = 0, \ldots, 3$, the compression lemma implies that every map of the form $f\colon (X, x_0) \to (BS^3, y_0)$ for some $x_0 \in X$, $y_0 \in BS^3$ is homotopic to a map with image $y_0$, i.e. nullhomotopic. $\Box$

What is there to elaborate? I told you how to construct one! On a different note, asking about homework from this course is not in any way illegal and you don't need to hide the fact that you're doing it, although for your own sake it might be better for you to spend some more time working on them by yourself. Since Lück's lecture notes are publicly available, it might be a good idea to link them so that people can see precisely what material we've covered. Signed, one of your tutors.
